# react testing library and jest with search input to update value on props

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

### Demo

The search has several props to handle debouncing and api calls being made. Therefor, the state of the search will be the following:

- Empty: shows a search-icon with no text in the input

[image]

- Recently typed text: shows a spinner(replacing the search-icon) to indicate a lookup is happening

[image]

- debounced typed text: after xSeconds, a clear-x-icon(replacing the spinner) shows with the typed out text.

[image]

---

### The Problem

I can't figure out how to get the unit test to update the passed value in the props after the input has been updated by the mock function.

---

### The Component Code

```
function SearchBox({
  isSearching,
  searchValue,
  handleSearch,
  clearSearch
}) {
  const classes = useSearchStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.searchContainer}>
      {isSearching ? (
        <div className={classes.spinnerContainer}>
          <Spinner />
        </div>
      ) : searchValue ? (
        <Button icon className={classes.clearIcon} onClick={clearSearch}>
          <ClearIcon />
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <SearchIcon className={classes.searchIcon} />
      )}
      <Input
        className={classes.searchInput}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        maxLength={500}
        value={searchValue}
        onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => handleSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

### The Test Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';

// ===========================================================================
// =============================== Setup Tests ===============================
// ===========================================================================
const searchValue = 'test';
const mockHandleSearchFn = jest.fn();
const mockClearSearchFn = jest.fn();
function TestContainer() {
  return (
    <SearchBox
      isSearching={false}
      searchValue=""
      handleSearch={mockHandleSearchFn}
      clearSearch={mockClearSearchFn}
    />
  );
}

// ===========================================================================
// =============================== Start Tests ===============================
// ===========================================================================
describe('SearchBox', () => {
  describe('should match snapshot when', () => {
    it('input is empty', () => {
      const testComponent = render(<TestContainer />);
      expect(testComponent.container).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
    it('then, enters text in input and handleSearch is invoked', async () => {
      const userViewer = userEvent.setup();
      render(<TestContainer />);
      const searchInput = await waitFor(() => screen.getByPlaceholderText(/Search/i));
      await userViewer.type(searchInput, searchValue);
      expect(mockHandleSearchFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(searchInput).toHaveAttribute('value', searchValue); // <------------------------ failing here
  });
```

---

### Tests Execution Output Example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you type into an `<input />` field, it doesn't set the `value` attribute. You can see this by typing into a plain input and inspecting the element.

The proper way to access the input value is via `toHaveValue`:

```js
expect(searchInput).toHaveValue(searchValue);
```

Comment: Noted, thanks. Test is still failing though. Looking at another answer where it seems it is best to write this expect in the parent component where the state is instantiated and passing the actual function to update the state: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479814/how-to-test-props-that-are-updated-by-an-onchange-handler-in-react-testing-libra